# Can a classical computer count beyond a finite number?

Tags: computer-science, computer-arithmetic

It seems since a classical computer has a finite number of transistors, it can only represent numbers up to a finite value. So a classical computer couldn't start at 1 and then count up to an arbitrary number. Can anyone confirm this or provide reasons otherwise?

Comment: The term you used is not right - you mean to ask "can a computer count to any given finite number as large as we wish?" Actually, in some way turing demonstrated that a machine can work for ever. The challenge will be the input the number first - and it will be in parts. Than you will need to write a special program to do the counting.

Comment: It depends what you mean by counting up. Is it bits that you count, or is it what the bits represent that you count. Is the increment 1, does every step have to be stored etc. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708461/biggest-number-in-computer-ever

Comment: How does this differ from our brains, which are made of a finite number of neurons (even atoms, if you wish)? Also, counting up to an arbitrary number (from text of your question) is not the same as counting beyond a finite number (from title of your question).

Comment: An individual computer has a very limited "lifetime" of only a few years.  And inasmuch as the amount of energy in the universe is finite, no computer or set of computers can "count" forever.  Finally, the universe will likely end in 50 billion years or so.  So, there's that.

Answer (score 1):

The counting limitation for a classical computer results from available memory, not from available processing power. For example, there are simple algorithms that can sequentially read the digits of an arbitrarily long binary number *N* and simultaneously write the digits of the number *N+1*. Rinse and repeat and your computer can count forever (in principle). There is no need to store the whole of *N* in the computer's memory so processing the algorithm is not limited by the 'size' or complexity of the computer itself.

Where the limitation is, is in the space required to store the 'written' digits. If you had unlimited external memory then in principle the computer could read and write (count) forever, but in practice there is a limit in the external memory based on how much data you can store in all the matter you have available.

So, in practice, the limitation is not in the computer itself - but in the storage limit of the visible universe.

Comment: It depends too if you use symbolic programs that have the notion of limit.

Comment: An individual computer has a very limited "lifetime."  And inasmuch as the amount of energy in the universe is finite, no computer or set of computers can "count" forever.  
Finally, the universe will likely end in 50 billion years or so.  So, there's that.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that there is no need to store the whole number. One can store a truncated version of the number and keep incrementing it, but I think this would be cheating. It doesn't seem there would be a use of counting. If I wanted to obtain the full number after a certain amount of time had passed, I wouldn't be able to. One could store parts of the number and operate on it, and then operate on other parts of the number, but where would the other parts of the number be stored?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for any actual physical computer, there is a finite number beyond which it will not be able to count, because there's only finitely many physical states it can be in.

I'm assuming you're also, at least a little bit, asking a different question:

> If all physical computers are finite, why do we model them with things like Turing machines, which have infinite amounts of memory?

That's because at the stage when we're using mathematical models like Turing machines, the memory size of physical computers is irrelevant. Generally:

- The first constraint on what computers can do is that some problems are undecidable: even a Turing machine will never be able to tell you the answer.
- Many actual decidable problems are more limited by *time* than *space*.
- Usually, algorithms scale, so that the same idea works on problems of any size, even if some problems can't be solved on physical computers today.

We do sometimes consider memory limitations. (For example, [PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE) is the set of all problems for which the memory needed to solve a length-$n$ instance is bounded by some polynomial in $n$.) But even then, we can just take a model with infinite memory, and then once it's done solving a problem, ask: how much memory did it use?

Comment: An individual computer has a very limited "lifetime" of only a few years. And inasmuch as the amount of energy in the universe is finite, no computer or set of computers can "count" forever. Finally, the universe will likely end in 50 billion years or so. So, there's that. –

Comment: I think there's a general principle at work that it's easier to say "there is no upper bound" than to say "there is an upper bound, but it's situational and not precisely known". We work with real numbers, which have unlimited precision, even though all our measurements can only give us so many decimal digits.